# read znode without using any zookeeper client

Tags: shell, apache-zookeeper

There is in my cluster a Zookeeper server (I know its IP) which stores my data. I cat get that data using a custom Java application.

**Is there any possibility to get the data from `/a/b` in a shell, without using the zkCli?** I do not have any zookeeper client installed and for various reasons it is complicated to install one.

I'm looking for something like `echo 'stat' | nc 10.xxx.yyy.zzz 2181`, but `echo 'get /a/b' | nc .....` do not retrieve anything.

Thanks :)

Comment: ZooKeeper is a complicated protocol for reasons innately linked to its core purpose -- you quite literally *must* talk to multiple servers, not just one, to be sure the answer you're getting is current.

Comment: Given that the content I have does rarely change, I do not really care to get the current version of the data. Do I have any chance to get the info? Thanks Charles :)

Comment: If you read Python, see https://github.com/python-zk/kazoo/blob/master/kazoo/protocol/serialization.py -- short form is that even if you ignore the operations a client needs to perform to know that its answers are current, the protocol is of the packed-binary variety, and thus not particularly amenable to implementation in shell.

Comment: (...if your "complicated reasons" preclude a JVM but not a Python library, though, you might seriously consider using kazoo).

Comment: Indeed, the protocol is far away from a simple shell implementation. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Please consider to aggregate your comments in an answer that I can accept later. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZooKeeper is a complicated protocol for reasons innately linked to its core purpose: A protocol-compliant client is required to communicate with multiple servers to ensure that the answer it receives is up-to-date.

Moreover, the protocol in question involves packed binary structures, making it inamenable to implementation in native shell.

---

I would suggest:

- If your restrictions against installing new software are in some way specific to the upstream Zookeeper client (for instance, specific to Java), consider an alternate client such as [zookeepercli](https://github.com/outbrain/zookeepercli) or (should you be amenable to writing some Python code) [Kazoo](https://kazoo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
- If you don't need the level of robustness Zookeeper's protocol otherwise guarantees, consider running a service on your ZooKeeper servers which uses a native client library to perform lookups, returning results over HTTP or raw sockets, thus allowing `curl` or `nc` to be used from your scripts elsewhere.

Comment: I've finally used Kazoo into a docker. Easy job. 2 lines for installation in Dockerfile,  4 lines of python code in order to get the node. Thanks Charles :)